# I cannot get on board ethernet nics to function

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

I have a SuperMicro X11SAT-F-O MB with an Intel E3-1270v5 3.6GHz CPU and with 16GB of ram. I have tried installing Ubuntu 14.04LTS Desktop, 16.04LTS Desktop and 17.04 LTS Desktop. I cannot get the either of the two onboard nics to function correctly. I am trying to connect to a 1000BaseT switch. The Network Control Panel recognizes that the connection is a Gigabit connection, but I cannot ever get a DHCP IP address. If I set a static IP address, the system indicates that the network is connected, but it will not pass any network traffic. I assume this must be a driver issue, but I cannot for the life of me find the appropriate LAN drivers for this motherboard chip set (Intel C236 Chipset). SuperMicro indicates that this MB should support the recent Ubuntu releases. Can anyone help me? Thanks!